# Stack Exchange site not rendering, instead shows code

Tags: support, xml

Please go to https://stackexchange.com/ , then go to the bottom and click on Hot Questions feed.

[image]

This will rediect you to https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions and gives XML code:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This page isn't supposed to be rendered. That's the source page for an RSS feed.

If you put that link as the source for a feed - such as Feedly, or the feeds built into Stack Exchange Chat - it will alert you to new questions that have become Hot Network Questions. But it's not supposed to be a rendered page.

Answer (score 7):

It's not HTML, it's XML, and a specific variation: it's an [RSS feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). It depends on your browser and what other programs you have installed what happens: the file will be downloaded, shown as code or opened in an [RSS reader](https://zapier.com/blog/best-rss-feed-reader-apps/) which you can use to keep track of new things ... new hot network questions in this case.

You can check the [feed](/questions/tagged/feed) [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feed/info) to see what kind of feeds are available on the Stack Exchange platform.